# Does Chrome's Developer Tool show response content when "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" is returned?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to analyse HTTPS traffic in the Developer Tool, but when I click the "Response" tab, it shows "Failed to load response data".

The response's header contains this:

> cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
>
> cache-control: post-check=0, pre-check=0

Is this what prevents the response from being shown? If so, how can I tell the Developer Tool to ignore that and record the responses anyway?

Comment: Not sure about your situation, but this error happens after navigating to a new page if "Preserve Log" is enabled.

Comment: Yeah, I had enabled it and the page navigates (form submission). Is there any way to preserve the response data?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. Not sure if responses are cleared on navigation or main frame navigation, so it's possible that the response will stay around if you put the page in an iframe.